# How to upper-case first letter

Tags: c++

How can I write a C program that reads your first and last names and than converts them to upper-case and lower-case letters...I know how upper and lower letters but dk how to do for first and last names..any sugegstion?...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int i;
char s[255];

int main()
{
    cin.get(s,255,'\n');
    int l=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
......................................


cout<<s; cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some character that separates a first and last name that you could look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the first and last names directly into `std::string`'s. There is no reason to manage the buffers yourself or guess what size they will or should be. This can be done with something like this

```
std::string first, last;

//  Read in the first and last name.
std::cin >> first >> last;
```

You will want to convert the string to upper/lower case based on your requirements. This can be done with `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` which are available in the C++ Standard Library. Just include `<cctype>` and they are available. There are several ways to do this but one easy way is to convert the entire string to lower case then convert the first character to upper case.

```
// set all characters to lowercase
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower);

//  Set the first character to upper case.
str[0] = static_cast<std::string::value_type>(toupper(str[0]));
```

Putting this all together you get something that looks a little like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void capitalize(std::string& str)
{
    //  only convert if the string is not empty
    if (str.size())
    {
        // set all characters to lowercase
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::tolower);

        //  Set the first character to upper case.
        str[0] = static_cast<std::string::value_type>(toupper(str[0]));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string first, last;

    //  Read in the first and last name.
    std::cin >> first >> last;

    //  let's capialize them.
    capitalize(first);
    capitalize(last);

    //  Send them to the console!
    std::cout << first << " " << last << std::endl;
}
```

Note: Including statements like `using namespace std;` is considered bad form as it pulls everything from the `std` namespace into the current scope. Avoid is as much as possible. If your professor/teacher/instructor uses it they should be chastised and forced to watch the movie Hackers until the end of time.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using C++, you should use `std::string` instead of a `char` array, and [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does exactly what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string first, last;
    while (std::getline(cin, first, ' '))
    {
         std::getline(cin, last);
         //Convert to upper, lower, whatever
    }
}
```

You can leave out the loop if you only want it to get one set of input per run.  The third parameter of `getline()` is a delimiter, which will tell the function to stop reading at when it reaches that character.  It is `\n` by default, so you don't need to include it if you want to read the rest of the line.